# magrittr pipe not evaluating a dot passed a second pipe within a function argument

Tags: r, magrittr

When using dot a second time to reuse the data on the left of a pipe, passing the dot to a function `. %>% f()` is different to putting the dot inside the function brackets `f(.)`. Why is this?

Debugging the %>% operator shows that . %>% identity() evaluates to a functional sequence rather than a character vector, which causes `names<-` to fail. I don't know how to force the evaluation of this.

```r
# Error
c('a', 'b', 'c') %>% `names<-`(., . %>% identity())
# Works
c('a', 'b', 'c') %>% `names<-`(., identity(.))
```

```
c('a', 'b', 'c') %>% `names<-`(., . %>% identity())
```

> Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
>     cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

```
c('a', 'b', 'c') %>% `names<-`(., identity(.))
# a   b   c 
#"a" "b" "c"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pipe starting with `.` generates a function.

For example, `. %>% identity` is same as `function(.) identity(.)`.

Thus,

```r
# Error
c('a', 'b', 'c') %>% `names<-`(., . %>% identity())
```

is regarded as

```r
c('a', 'b', 'c') %>% `names<-`(., function(.) identity(.))
```

which means the second argument of `names<-` is function, not a character vector.

This is documented in [Using the dot-place holder as lhs](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html).

In order to workaround, try

```r
c('a', 'b', 'c') %>% `names<-`(., (.) %>% identity())
```

Comment: I would like to add that `magrittr` has a operator for setting the names, in this case use `letters[1:3] %>% magrittr::set_names({ . })` (same rule as above).

Comment: You are right. Though I prefer `rlang::set_names` because it uses first argument as new names if names are not specified explicitly.
`letters[1:3] %>% rlang::set_names()` works without dot.